# Converter RGB para Hexadecimal com JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tenho que converter valor rgb para hex quando mover os inputs(range), mas quando eu movo não acontece nada, a cor hexadecimal deve aparecer em baixo também na medida que a cor for mudada em cima.

A cor é carregada apenas quando a página carrega, quando movo os ranges não acontece nada.

Segue código: https://codepen.io/fmm312/pen/zWKYyX

Comment: Se a resposta ajudou e/ou está correta, marca como correta pra ajudar as outras pessoas que possuam o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 5):

Uma forma de fazer isso é com as seguintes funções:

```
function componentToHex(c) {
    var hex = c.toString(16);
    return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}

alert(rgbToHex(0, 51, 255)); // #0033ff
```

Para mais informações, acessa esse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb).